# How to drive the DDS Compiler IP core from Xilinx

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, soc, redpitaya

I completed [Anton Potočniks' introductory guide](http://antonpotocnik.com/?p=514765) to the red pitaya board and I am now able to send commands from the linux machine running on the SoC to its FPGA logic.

I would like to further modify the project so that I can control the phase of the signal that is being transmitted via the red pitayas' DAC. Some pins (from 7 down to 1) of the first GPIO port were still unused so I started setting them from within the OS and used the red pitaya's LEDs to confirm that they were being set without interfering with the functionality of Anton Potočnik's "high bandwidth averager".

I then set the [DDS_compilers'](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/dds_compiler/v6_0/pg141-dds-compiler.pdf) to Phase Offset Programmability to "streaming" mode so that it can be configured on the fly using the bits that are currently controling the red pitaya's LEDs. I used some slices to connect my signals to the [AXI4-Stream Constant](https://github.com/apotocnik/redpitaya_guide/blob/master/cores/axis_constant_v1_0/axis_constant.v) IP core, which in turn drives the DDS compiler.

[image: my current setup]

Unfortunately the DAC is just giving me a constant output of 500 mV.

I created a new project with a  testbench for the DDS compiler, because synthesis takes a long time and doesn't give me much insight into what is happening.

[image: simulation results from a testbench containing the DDS compiler]

Unfortunately all the output signals of the DDS compiler are undefined.

My question:

What am I doing wrong and how can I proceed to control DACs' phase?

---

EDIT1; [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpbrxzlnb02ns7j/edit1.txt?dl=0) is my test bench

The IP core is configured as follows, so many of the control signals that I provided should not be required:

[image: IP core configurations]

---

EDIT2; I changed declarations of the form `m_axis_data_tready => '0'` to `m_axis_phase_tready => m_axis_phase_tready_signal`. I also took a look at the wrapper file called `dds_compiler_0.vhd` and saw that it treats both `m_axis_phase_tready` and `m_axis_data_tready` as inputs.

My simulation results remained unchanged...

My new test bench can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv8rnlmp22fp694/edit2.txt?dl=0).

---

EDIT3: Vivado was just giving me the old simulation results - creating a new testbench, deleting the file under `<project_name>.sim/sim_1/behav/xsim/simulate.log` and restarting vivado solved this problem.

I noticed that the wrapper file (`dds_compiler_0.vhd`) only has five ports:

1. `aclk` (in)
2. `s_axis_phase_tvalid` (in)
3. `s_axis_phase_tdata` (in)
4. `m_axis_data_tvalid` (out)
5. and `m_axis_data_tdata` (out)

So I removed all the unnecessary control signals and got a new simulation result, but I am still not recieving any useful output from the dds_compiler:
[image: without control signals]

The corresponding testbench can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ushbs553h165lnx/edit3_no_control_signals.txt?dl=0).

I also don't get any valid output when I include the control signals.
[image: with control signals]

The corresponding testbench can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbhsbi9fpo2fef4/edit3_control_signal_part.txt?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like m_axis_data_tready is not connected. No data will come out unless that's asserted.

Comment: Good point! My test bench now contains `m_axis_data_tready <= '1';` and `m_axis_phase_tready <= '1';`, but the simmulation results didn't change. I think there are some mor problems with my test bench, I will add the code to my question...

Comment: phase_tready should be an output from the DDS. Are you sure some of the U's didn't change to X when you added that code?

Comment: Yes, all the outputs are still U's, but I noticed that I was connecting some ports to constants instead of signals (like `m_axis_phase_tready => '0'`). I am now mapping the ports of `dds_compiler_0` to their respective signals and I still have undefined outputs (see EDIT2).

Comment: I don't see any TB code that matches any of those waveforms, so it's hard to say. But in the simple setup without all the control signals, you should not be seeing the 'U' output.

Comment: Sorry, I left out some testbenches because my question was getting very verbose. All the testbenches have now been attached as external links. The problem with the `U` at the `m_axis_..._tready` signals was resolved after renaming the testbench and restarting vivado. Maybe now the problem is with the content of my input?